# Вывод сообщений из тг на экран

Tags: python, telebot, tkinter

Пробую сделать функцию в боте(telebot), для отправки "послания" на экран компьютера.
Необходимо выводить текст отправленный человеком боту в отдельное окно(tkinter или другое) на компьютере.
Помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: А в чем проблема? Что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну можно и без `tkinter`, например, используя `ctypes` и `MessageBoxW`. У меня пример на `Client`, у вас может быть на боте. Так как вы не указали куда выводить окно, оно будет выводится на хосте, который запустил бота.

```
import ctypes
from pyrogram import Client, filters

api_id = 'апи_ид' 
api_hash = 'апи_хаш' 
bot_token='токен бота'
bot = Client("my_bot", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, bot_token=bot_token)

accessUsers = []  # Здесь вам нужно добавить список пользователей, которым разрешено использовать команду

@bot.on_message(filters.command("attention"))
def help_command(client, message):
    if message.chat.id in accessUsers:
        message.reply_text("Предупреждение отправлено")
        MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
        MessageBox(None, message.text.replace("/attention", ""), 'АХТУНГ!', 0)

bot.run()
```

Выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!)